# visual basic asp.net page sometimes renders incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have hunted around for this one online but can't find anything like this issue, so if you know of a site please point me in the direction!  I have a visual basic asp.net website, written in asp.net 3.5 using visual studio 2010.

I have designed a customised selection of boxes along the top of one page, consisting of a series of image buttons and panels.  When you press one image button, the panel for it is shown and all others are hidden, effectively creating a horizontal concertina.  Please see below markup (please note there are lists etc in each panel except panelParameters, but as they are not relevant to the issue I have removed them):

```
        <asp:Panel ID="panelParameters" runat="server" Height="300"
            BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="5px" Direction="LeftToRight"
            BorderColor="#00539F" Visible="False" CssClass="parameterPanel">
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelArea" runat="server" Visible="true">
            &nbsp;
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgArea1" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="4%" ImageUrl="~/Images/Panels/Area1Panel.png" CssClass="inlineBlock" />
                <asp:Panel ID="panelArea1" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="71%" CssClass="inlineBlock">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSection" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="4%" ImageUrl="~/Images/Panels/SectionPanel.png" CssClass="inlineBlock" />
                <asp:Panel ID="panelSection" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="71%"  CssClass="inlineBlock">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDate" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="4%" ImageUrl="~/Images/Panels/datePanel.png" CssClass="inlineBlock" />
                <asp:Panel ID="panelDate" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="71%" CssClass="inlineBlock">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgResponse" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="4%" ImageUrl="~/Images/Panels/ResponsePanel.png" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="inlineBlock" />
                <asp:Panel ID="panelResponse" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="71%"  CssClass="inlineBlock">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgArea1Compare" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="4%" ImageUrl="~/Images/Panels/Area1ComparePanel.png" CssClass="inlineBlock" />
                <asp:Panel ID="panelArea1Compare" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="71%"  CssClass="inlineBlock">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSectionCompare" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="4%" ImageUrl="~/Images/Panels/SectionComparePanel.png" CssClass="inlineBlock" /> 
                <asp:Panel ID="panelSectionCompare" runat="server" Height="160px" Width="71%"  CssClass="inlineBlock">
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
```

For the images and the panels, I have used a cssClass which is written in my css as:

```
.inlineBlock
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:none;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

I am using the vb pages to control when the panels are shown and hidden on the 'visible' switch.  This works perfectly when the project is run locally on my laptop.  I have published the website to an internal web server, and it's fine when I look at it on there.  It is also SOMETIMES fine when viewing this on client computers (using the published site on the web server), however on other computers running the same OS image, same version of IE, same resolution and monitor size, for some reason the inline bit isn't working correctly, and the panels appear one below the other instead.

Our internal web developers are stumped on this one so I'm really hoping one of you guys has an idea; if any more code is needed or screen prints of the issue etc I'm happy to provide.

Comment: I'd be tempted to check the security settings in IE along with if this is happening for the same accounts as it could be a security issue for something else to check here.

Comment: it doesn't appear to be security related - I have tested this with my own logon and it seems to be down to 'some' computers work and others don't.  Sadly it's about 80% where it doesn't work!!

Answer (score 1):

Same version of IE does not mean same mode.  Use the F12 key and test in all browser modes.  There are serious differences between IE9 mode and IE9 Compatibility View mode.

Comment: pressing F12 doesn't do anything on my browser (I have IE8, having missed the company-wide update to IE9!) but have also tried this in IE9 and it doesn't do anything?  I have however checked and it isn't in compatability mode...

Comment: That is odd.  IE8 had the developer tools as well.  Should also be on the Tools menu, as an item called F12 developer tools.

Comment: It's there, under the tools menu, but when I click on it nothing happens?  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: It should pop up another window with the developer tools.  If you are not getting the developer window, I don't know what to tell you. The F12 tools are the only way I know to test more than one version of IE.  You say you are *not* running in compatibility mode.  My point is your clients who are getting bad results *might* be.  If your F12 tools are not working, try another way of turning on compatibility mode.

Comment: Also, maybe a good time to get caught up on that company wide upgrade :)

Comment: I've tested this on client machines, who do have IE9, and nothing happens when pressing F12 or going to the option manually.  I have also checked their url bar as I'm pretty sure compatability mode shows up there as a broken page icon, and everything looks normal, so I'm sure that it isn't.  Sadly, the company wide update can't be applied to me until they do the last office in a month!!  But the guys around me are pretty good guinea pigs :)  Thank you for your suggestions